# Enable user registration - eJabberd

Tags: ubuntu, file-sharing, local-area-network, ejabberd, instant-messaging

I am a complete n00b to configuring Jabber/XMPP servers and I am hoping to get some help getting set up. I have done all of [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpJabberServer) and installed [pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/). I seem to be able set up my "admin-user" in pidgin no problem but when I try to register a new user I get a 403 Fobidden message back from pidgin.

Do I need to change the ejabberd.cfg file to allow users to register? If so how do I go about it? If not what do I need to get basic chat and fileshare going?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options regarding user registration. You can either manually create user accounts on the server, or you can enable in-band registration, which allows anyone who can connect to the server to register an account.

If you want to create accounts manually, run this on the server for each user:

```
sudo ejabberdctl register <username> <domain> <password>
```

If you want to enable in-band registration, find the following line in `/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.cfg` and change the `deny` to `allow` so that it looks like this.

```
{access, register, [{allow, all}]}.
```

Comment: Awesome that worked thanks. Any info on how I can get registered uses to be able to chat?!!

Comment: The users need to add each other to their rosters, and should then be able to send messages.

Answer (score 0):

Related to mgorven's answer above, here is a little script I use to dump useful information about registered users to stdout.  The ejabberdctl dump command requires a file rather than stdout, which is why I do all the other nonsense below:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo ejabberdctl dump /tmp/etmpdump.txt
sudo chown $LOGNAME /tmp/etmpdump.txt
grep "{passwd,{" </tmp/etmpdump.txt | sed -e 's/{passwd,{"//g;s/","/ /g;s/"},"/ /g;s/"}.//g' | sort
rm -f /tmp/etmpdump.txt
```